# Is it possible to peek at the next value in a DataTable Row?

Tags: vb.net

I have a DataTable that contains 4 rows.  I want to compare a value in one column in row 1 with the value in row 2.  Something similar to this:

```
For Each row As DataRow in drRows
  If row("column") <> row("column") 'I want the second row("column") to be the next row.
     'do something else
  End If
Next
```

Comment: You can access `drRows` using the indexer.

Comment: Is this the only way and since I am using For Each, I guess I would have to check that I don't go over the index value, correct?

Comment: You don't have to use `For Each`. You can do a `For` loop with an index, just be sure not to go over.

Comment: Would you mind providing an example, I am still slightly confused since I am already doing row("column"), how would I tell it I don't want the current row("column"), but the next one.

Comment: `For i = 0 To drRows.Count - 1` and use `row(i)` and `row(i + 1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always access a `DataRow` with its index ([`DataRowCollection.Item`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowcollection.item.aspx)):

```
For i As Integer = 0 To tbl.Rows.Count - 1
    Dim row As DataRow = tbl.Rows(i)
    If i <> tbl.Rows.Count - 1 Then
        Dim nextRow As DataRow = tbl(i + 1)
        If row("column").Equals(nextRow("column")) Then
            'do something"
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Comment: I am trying this, but it is saying Class System.Data.DataTable cannot be indexed because it has no Default property.

Comment: Why don't you loop to `tbl.Rows.Count - 2` instead of making the check each time?

Comment: @minitech - Wouldn't this miss the last row.

Comment: @Xaisoft: It would, but there's no row after the last row to compare it to. And that's what it already does...

Comment: @minitech - Ok, but in my case, I still need the last row anyway.

Comment: Then you don't have .NET 4.0. I think it's an extension method, sorry. Thanks for editing. @minitech: I don't know the OP's exact requirement. He might need to do things in the last row too, but he can't compare it with lastrow+1.

Comment: @Xaisoft: Okay. You can do `tbl.Rows.Last()` then. That applies to my answer too.

Answer (score 4):

You keep track of the last item:

```
Dim last As DataRow = Nothing

For Each row As DataRow In drRows
    If last IsNot Nothing Then
        ' Compare last with row
    End If

    last = row
Next
```

Comment: This is closest to what I have, but need a bit help understanding it.  Basically, when I go through the Foreach, I want to compare the current row with the next row, if the current row is different from the next row, I want to update one of the other rows columns.  Looks like you are comparing current with last, I want to compare current with next.

Comment: @Xaisoft: You can compare the two rows, right? `last` will be the last row, `row` will be the current row, each time around. If you need to change another row, you can use `drRows.Rows(indexOfYourRow)` to access the other row by index.

Answer (score 1):

Say you have the following table:

```
A   B    C   D
1   2    3   4
5   6    7   8 
9   10   11  12
12  12   13  14
```

```
For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 2
   If dt.Rows(i)("ColName") <> dt.Rows(i + 1)("ColName") Then    
       'Do something
   End If
Next
```

Comment: @minitech : I think it will miss the last row

Comment: Check the revision history, your C# code is nearly identical.